# decoding ISO characters

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I got Chinese characters encoded in ISO-8859-1, for example `&#20860; = 兼`
Those characters are taken form the database using AJAX and sent by Json using json_encode.
I then use the template Handlebars to set the data on the page.
When I look at the ajax page the characters are displayed correctly, the source is still encoded.
But the final result displays the encrypted characters.

I tried to decode on the javascript part with `unescape` but there is no foreach with the template that gives me the possibility to decode the specific variable, so it crashes.
I tried to decode on the PHP side with `htmlspecialchars_decode` but without success.

Both pages are encoded in ISO-8859-1, but I can change them in UTF8 if necessary, but the data in the database remains encoded in ISO-8859-1.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There are no Chinese characters in ISO-8859-1, you're probably using utf-8

Comment: Type `&#20860;` in Google and it'll automatically transformed into `兼` o.O However I tried `decodeURIComponent` but it doesn't work. Sorry.

Comment: The page and the database are in ISO-8859-1 I checked it many times, and this kind of encoding `&#20860;` is iso kind... The dev that did that is really stupid I know...

Comment: When you say "encoded in ISO-8859-1," you mean "encoded as numeric entities," I guess. So, you're saying that when you view the included-with-AJAX results, you see the entity encoding and not the actual character, right?

Comment: +John Flatness that is right !

Comment: @Derek—[decodeURIComponent](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.3.2) is for decoding strings encoded with [encodeURIComponent](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.3.4), which is used to make strings safe to pass in URIs. It doesn't convert character codes to characters (or vice versa), e.g. `' '` (space) becomses `%20`

Comment: It seems that the json_encode encodes the special char, so &# is transformed to another thing, so the final result is messed up... That is only what I guess cause I can't see the source it's AJAX. By the way is there a way to see the source generated ? Cause the chrome inspector gives what we see...

Comment: Your main problem is that your text is "&#20860;" and not "兼". If you want "兼" you should handle it as the character "兼" in an appropriate character encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you including your text with the "double-stache" Handlebars syntax?

```
{{your expression}}
```

As the Handlebars documentation mentions, that syntax HTML-escapes its output, which would cause the results you're mentioning, where you're seeing the entity `&#20860;`  instead of `兼`.

Using three braces instead ("triple-stache") won't escape the output and will let the browser correctly interpet those numeric entities:

```
{{{your expression}}}
```

Comment: That did the trick !
Thank you very much !! I read it but wasn't thinking about that.

Answer (score 3):

You're simply representing your characters in HTML entities. If you want them as "actual characters", you'll need to use an encoding that can represent those characters, ISO-8859 won't do. `htmlspecialchars_decode` doesn't work because it only decodes a handful of characters that are *special* in HTML and leaves other characters alone. You'll need [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) to decode all entities, and you'll need to provide it with a character set to decode to which can handle Chinese characters, UTF-8 being the obvious best choice:

```
$str = html_entity_decode($str, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

You'll then need to make sure the browser knows that you're sending it UTF-8. If you want to store the text in the database in UTF-8 as well (which you really should), best follow the guide [How to handle UTF-8 in a web app](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) which explains all the pitfalls.

Comment: Thank you for your reply it will be useful for another time.
but actually +John Flatness gave me the trick that works, I +1 your effort.